# How do I aggregate fragment URLs when viewing content pageviews?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics dashboard.

I'm viewing pageviews for individual pages (Behavior > Site Content > All Pages).

I'm seeing results like the example below.

```
page title          page views
------------------------------
/blog/a.html        1000
/blog/b.html        500
/blog/c.html        100
/blog/a.html#yo     20
/blog/a.html#sup    10
/blog/b.html#foo    5
```

I want to aggregate the results so that they just tell me the total amount of views per page. So, `/blog/a.html` would have 1030, `/blog/b.html` would have 505.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a regex filter to group things together in an advanced filter:

```
^\/blog\/a\.html($|#.*)
```

would group both /blog/a.html and /blog/a.html#yo and any others, etc.